# Python best pattern for cross reference

Tags: python, python-import

My program is using two different communication channels, and in some cases, I need to publish received events from one channel into another. So the basic structure is something like this:

```
--fileA.py--
  class ChannelA:
    def __init__(self, data_store):
      self.store = data_store

    def read(self):
      # Listen for messages on this channel and publish them to another channel.
      self.store.update()

    def publish(self):
      # Send a message over this channel
      self.store.update()

--fileB.py--
  class ChannelB:
    def __init__(self, data_store)
      self.store = data_store
      
    def read(self):
      # Listen for messages on this channel and publish them to another channel.
      self.store.update()

    def publish(self):
      # Send a message over this channel
      self.store.update()

--main.py--
    from fileStore import DataStore
    from fileA import ChannelA
    from fileB import ChannelB


    def main():
      data = DataStore()
      channel_A = ChannelA(data)
      channel_A.read()
      channel_B = ChannelB(data)
      channel_B.read()

    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

So what I would like to achieve in the is that I could for example inside `ChannelA` call a method `ChannelB.publish()` and vice versa.

I could of course add ChannelA instance to ChannelB constructor parameter, but I can't do the same for ChannelA, since ChannelB had not yet been created:

```
class ChannelB:
  def __init__(self, data_store, channel)
    self.store = data_store
    self.channel = channel
```

One simple way of doing this would be to just initialize both communication channels inside a single class and call the methods inside, but this is something I would like to avoid if possible.

Another simple way of solving this could for example be to just define both instances in the main class and later access them via deferred imports:

```
--main.py--
from fileStore import DataStore
from fileA import ChannelA
from fileB import ChannelB

def publish_A():
  channel_A.publish()

def publish_B():
  channel_B.publish()

data = DataStore()
channel_A = ChannelA(data)
channel_B = ChannelB(data)

def main():
  channel_A.read()
  channel_B.read()
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

--fileA.py--
...
def publish(self):
  import main
  main.publish_B()
  self.store.update()
...
```

My question here is, what is the best or preferred way to solve such cases in Python?

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was the following:

```
--fileA.py--
  class ChannelA:
    def __init__(self, data_store):
      self.store = data_store
      self.publish_other = None

    def on_publish_other(self, callback):
      self.publish_other = callback

    def read(self):
      # Listen for messages on this channel and publish them to another channel.
      self.store.update()

    def publish(self):
      # Send a message over this channel
      if self.publish_other:
        self.publish_other()
      self.store.update()

--main.py--
    from fileStore import DataStore
    from fileA import ChannelA
    from fileB import ChannelB


    def main():
      data = DataStore()
      channel_A = ChannelA(data)
      channel_B = ChannelB(data)
      channel_A.on_publish_other(channel_B.publish)
      channel_A.read()
      channel_B.read()

    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```